# Query on dremel-linked tables stopped working

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 3 dremel-linked tables: 2 identity tables and 1 table connecting 2 identity tables.

Table A (4500 rows):

- a_id (key);
- a_attr1;
- a_attr2.

Table B (1500 rows):

- b_id (key);
- b_attr1;
- b_attr2.

Table C (700 rows):

- a_id;
- b_id.

The simplified query is:

```
    SELECT
      A.a_id,
      a_attr1,
      GROUP_CONCAT(STRING(b_attr1)) AS b_attr1,
      STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(NOW(), '%a %e-%b-%Y %R %Z'),
      SUM(b_attr2) AS b_attr2
    FROM [dataspace_name]:[project_name]:[dataset_name].A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT
         b_id,
         b_attr1,
         b_attr2,
         a_id
       FROM [dataspace_name]:[project_name]:[dataset_name].B
       JOIN [dataspace_name]:[project_name]:[dataset_name].C
         ON [dataspace_name]:[project_name]:[dataset_name].B.b_id = [dataspace_name]:{project_name]:[dataset_name].C.b_id
      ) AS BC
       ON A.a_id = BC.a_id
     WHERE
       a_attr2 = 1
     GROUP BY
       a_attr1
     HAVING
       (b_attr2 IS NULL) OR (b_attr2 > 0)
     ORDER BY
       a_attr1
     ;
```

This query was running fine for several months until last Monday, 5/13/2013.

The error message I get is:

Large table C must appear as the leftmost table in a join query.

I tried to re-write the query following the error message and swapping the tables, but I get the same message about most right table.

Any advice on what may be causing the failure and how to fix the query is much appreciated.

Comment: It was solved, the query is working again, and if anybody interested, it was done by replacing  "JOIN  [dataspace_name]:[project_name]:[dataset_name].C"  with "JOIN **EACH** [dataspace_name]:[project_name]:[dataset_name].C"

Answer (score 0):

It was solved, the query is working again, and if anybody interested, it was done by replacing `JOIN [dataspace_name]:[project_name]:[dataset_name].C` with `JOIN EACH [dataspace_name]:[project_name]:[dataset_name].C`